# Google Play Developer Console Errors : Signed APK Config Error, Achievements and Leaderboards unexpected error

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have two errors with Google Play Game Service :

**1/ Error when trying to sign in with google game services with signed APK.**

I updated version 6 of my game without any problems. At the 7th version, I have this error in my game :

```
*10-28 13:35:03.876: W/eph(3638): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}
10-28 13:35:03.886: E/Volley(3638): [61016] iu.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/110237988596880924057
10-28 13:35:03.936: E/SignInIntentService(3638): There is no linked app associated with this client ID.
10-28 13:35:03.936: E/SignInIntentService(3638): axj
10-28 13:35:03.936: E/SignInIntentService(3638):    at ast.a(SourceFile:151)
10-28 13:35:03.936: E/SignInIntentService(3638):    at ajd.a(SourceFile:228)
10-28 13:35:03.936: E/SignInIntentService(3638):    at ajd.a(SourceFile:209)
10-28 13:35:03.936: E/SignInIntentService(3638):    at ail.a(SourceFile:514)
10-28 13:35:03.936: E/SignInIntentService(3638):    at azv.a(SourceFile:202)
10-28 13:35:03.936: E/SignInIntentService(3638):    at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:324)
10-28 13:35:03.936: E/SignInIntentService(3638):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
10-28 13:35:03.936: E/SignInIntentService(3638):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 13:35:03.936: E/SignInIntentService(3638):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 13:35:03.936: E/SignInIntentService(3638):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
10-28 13:35:03.946: E/LoadSelfFragment(3788): Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID*
```

The dialog message returned is :

> The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name
>   and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developper
>   Console. also, if application is not yet published, check that account
>   you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account. See logs
>   for more information.

of course, I controlled the identifier of the application, SHA1 signature, nothing to report.
I deleted / added the signing of the application, always the same problem.
My game is in testing, I checked the 2 lists testers, nothing to report, I delete / add all testers no change.
At the end, I went in the publication Google Play Game Service, still unable to get a connection to google game play service.

Only the debug version can now connect with Game Service without any problems.

I have since noticed that sometimes a configuration error message appears in the console on the "APK files" page.

**2/ Google Play Developer Console Error : unexpected error in Achievements and Leaderboards page**

I recently added a achievement with the console. No problems at all. This success was much added to the list of successes and recognized by my game.

The next day, it is impossible to list the achievements and leaderboards in the console: Error Message Appears with blank page *Unexpected error. Please try again later.* In my game, no problem.

At the moment I have no idea of solution, help me, please!

Comment: That's 2 months since the signature issue blocking my development, a response from the project team?

Comment: A solution, for me it's works!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756769/android-play-games-services-is-incorrectly-configured-anyone-know-how-to-fix/20984145#20984145

Answer (score 1):

If it can bring you some relief, I have the same problem (#2) on the console.
I've read some topics on the issue on the net and it was adivised to sign off then sign on again, but it didn't solve the problem for me.

I think it's Google-related and not a project issue.

Comment: Thank you for your return, I feel less alone;-).
I will contact the Google team, I would make a return on it's problems.

Comment: I don't know what you did, but you definitely did something. Mine works again, and better than it ever did : number of players, percentage of achievements, etc. are correctly updated whereas they were not before.  
  
Did you contact the Google team ? Or were they upgrading the service ?

Comment: For Leaderboardss and achievements, it now works with the new features. this bug is solved for me.