# android play games services is incorrectly configured. anyone know how to fix?

Tags: android, google-play-games

[image]I have a weird bug that's cropped up.

My app works perfectly when I sign it with the android debug key store. But when I sign it with my own key, users are unable to sign in.

I get the message 
"The application is incorrectly configured. Check the package name and signing cerificate match the client id in the developer console"

I have done this and have added a new client I'd with the correct certificate and package name but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Anyone know what else I could try or if there is a known issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok all here is how I managed to fix it after a lot of trial and error.

1. If you have created a client id in the google api console for your release certificate sha1 and release package name then delete it.
2. Go into the developer play store console and follow the steps to link another app 
   ( screenshot below) 
   [image]

Then proceed to follow the steps that it takes you through which will create a new client id.

3. Now this is the important bit....

( Even though the UI will look the same and Google will give no visual indication that you need to do anything more to get it working and make you assume that changes have been autosaved) Press the publish button.  It will then give you a list of changes that it needs to publish.

Press publish and after a few hours your app will start to work.

Hooray

Comment: I will give it a try and tell here... 
Thank you!

Comment: I don't get it, If i am uploading the same apk to both, play store and amazon store, how come it seems that my client id is not working from the amazon app store?

By just re-creating the client id, it should work?

Comment: This applies to debug signin as well, e.g. if you use another device to develop. It's okay not to delete previous link, as it is allowed to link up to 20 app.

Comment: @XavierGuzman Did you enable anti-piracy in Google Developer Console ? Perhaps that is what prevent it from working properly in the amazon app store... (just a guess).

Comment: @John fortunately, I was able to solve it with this answer...I blogged about it, if you are facing the same issue: http://blog.xavierguzman.com/google-play-game-services-in-the-amazon-app-store/

Comment: I'm unable to resolve problem. I have deleted and created linked apps many times. I have created two keystores for release and debug, to get different certificate SHA1, and linked it. I have enable different email accounts on testing. I have different tutorials and stack overflow answers. Nothing works. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Try our troubleshooting guide: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting

In our experience, most problems of this nature can be solved by carefully following the steps indicated there.

Comment: I think you should really outpoint somewhere that it might take hours until changes to testing accounts are applied. The message "incorrectly configured" is highly misleading.

Comment: The linked troubleshooting page seems to not match current Google Play Dev Console. Specifically I do not find a list of client ids, and also the "Linked apps" is not found where the troubleshoot page notes, it is currently found if going Game Services>(game)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I forgot that in Android Studio you can't directly send an app to your device if it is a game being played through Google Play. If you do, you will get this error message. You have to instead in the Build menu of Android Studio, select Generate Signed APK..., and then send the app to your device from a console using the command "adb -d install <'app name'>.apk."  Then since I had previously sent the app to my device directly from Android Studio, I proceeded to get the error message from adb of "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES."  To fix this, I had to delete from my device the app which I had previously downloaded from Android Studio.  Then the command "adb -d install <'app name'>.apk" worked, and the app ran correctly.