# Google Play Services does not work after export

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

When I run my app in Eclipse, Google Play Services works normal. But when I export signed application package and install myapp.apk to my phone, app display error The app is incorectly configured....

Comment: possible duplicate [android play games services is incorrectly configured. anyone know how to fix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756769/android-play-games-services-is-incorrectly-configured-anyone-know-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of a directory change, your phone can't find the proper files to launch the app anymore. Try to re-install the app, this will set the right paths and should solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try by updating your device's "Google Play Services". It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try checking copy to my project/workspace option when import google-pay-services-lib in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an OAuth Client ID with the certificate fingerprint from the key that you use for signing the exported application?

Maybe you created one for the debug key (which is the key Eclipse uses when launching the app), but forgot to create and link another one for your release key.

You can find detailed information here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_3_generate_an_oauth_20_client_id

After you created the second client ID át the google api console, linking it to the game is not so trivial: you have to link the already linked app again, and you will see that this time it will show the second client ID.

Good luck.