# libgdx - publishing google play services error

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've tried publishing my game on Google Play and everything went fine except that everybody gets the same error when login to google play services.

Here's that error message:

[image]

I've been developing with `libgdx` using Eclipse IDE.

I think it may cause because `eclipse` export my project not in `release mode`, but i can't find how to change this with libgdx.

Please help me to fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756769/android-play-games-services-is-incorrectly-configured-anyone-know-how-to-fix

Comment: @Virus you're amazing, thanks dude, much love, happy new year! 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dreamchasers.pigpong.android here is my game, you helped me publishing it, thanks!